# pybind11 typecaster returning garbage

Tags: casting, pybind11

I'm implementing a Pybind11 module where the Python client can call some C++ functions passing Python tuples that are automatically converted to C++ vec2/vec3/vec4 objects (these are simple class that represent 2/3/4 dimensional vectors).

Now, I have setup the following type casters (I know there are no error checks, but I kept everything as simple as possible to try to understand where the problem is).

```
        template <> struct type_caster<glm::vec2> {
        public:

        PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(glm::vec2, const_name("vec2"));

            bool load(handle src, bool) {

                auto tuple = src.cast<pybind11::tuple>();
                value.x = tuple[0].cast<float>();
                value.y = tuple[1].cast<float>();

                return true;
            }

            static handle cast(glm::vec2 src, return_value_policy /* policy */, handle /* parent */) {
                return PyTuple_Pack(2, PyFloat_FromDouble(src.x), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.y));// PyLong_FromLong(src.long_value);
            }
        };

        template <> struct type_caster<glm::vec3> {
        public:

            PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(glm::vec3, const_name("vec3"));

            bool load(handle src, bool convert) {

                auto tuple = src.cast<pybind11::tuple>();
                value.x = tuple[0].cast<float>();
                value.y = tuple[1].cast<float>();
                value.z = tuple[2].cast<float>();

                return true;
            }

            static handle cast(glm::vec3 src, return_value_policy /* policy */, handle /* parent */) {
                return PyTuple_Pack(3, PyFloat_FromDouble(src.x), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.y), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.z));// PyLong_FromLong(src.long_value);
            }
        };
        template <> struct type_caster<glm::vec4> {
        public:
        PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(glm::vec4, const_name("vec4"));
            bool load(handle src, bool) {

                auto tuple = src.cast<pybind11::tuple>();
                value.x = tuple[0].cast<float>();
                value.y = tuple[1].cast<float>();
                value.z = tuple[2].cast<float>();
                value.w = tuple[3].cast<float>();
                return true;
            }

            static handle cast(glm::vec4 src, return_value_policy /* policy */, handle /* parent */) {
                return PyTuple_Pack(4, PyFloat_FromDouble(src.x), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.y), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.z), PyFloat_FromDouble(src.w));// PyLong_FromLong(src.long_value);
            }
        };
```

Now, I'm testing this C++ function exported in the Python module:

```
float test(const pybind11::kwargs& args) {
    auto pos = args["position"].cast<glm::vec3>();
    return pos.x;
}
```

This function seems to work well with vec2 and vec4, but returns garbage in pos for vec3. It could be that I'm doing all wrong, but I don't really understand what is going on here.